# ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [DELETE]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm trying to delete a record from my database using angularJS and rails, but when the delete action fires it shows a error.

In the browser log it shows

```
DELETE http://localhost:3000/movies.json/1 404 (Not Found)
```

And in the rails console it shows,

```
Started DELETE "/movies.json/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-08-26 09:42:07 +0200

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [DELETE] "/movies.json/1"):
```

`localhost:3000/movies.json` is available, so I'm not sure if I missed something in the routes or that I'm not targeting the id of the record propperly.

In my routes.rb I have,

```
resources :movies, only: [:create, :destroy, :index, :show]
```

This is the AngularJS service,

```
.factory('removeMovie', ['$http', function($http) {
  return {
    deleteMovie: function(movieId) {
    var _movieId =  parseInt(movieId);
    return $http.delete('/movies.json/'+_movieId);
  }
 };
}])
```

And the AngularJS controller,

```
$scope.deleteMovie = function(movie){
  removeMovie.deleteMovie(movie.id).then(function(sucessResponse){
    //success callback
  },function(errorResponse){
    //Error callback
  })
}
```

And this is the template in which the action starts,

```
%div{"ng-repeat" => "movie in movies"}
  {{ movie.id }}
  {{ movie.title }}
  %a{"ng-click" => "deleteMovie(movie)"}delete
```

Although I'm pretty sure it's not a AngularJS problem but a Rails problem. It's weird because I have `destroy` in my movie resources but the error says there's nog route match.

If I remove the `:create` from the resources I get the same error (but then POST instead of delete) when I try to create a new entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

controller.json/id is the wrong format for the URL, it should be controller/id.json. You need to change the delete method URL generation:

```
.factory('removeMovie', ['$http', function($http) {
  return {
    deleteMovie: function(movieId) {
    var _movieId =  parseInt(movieId);
    return $http.delete('/movies/'+_movieId + '.json');
  }
 };
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess the path should be `/movies/1.json`.

Comment: Yup, that was indeed the problem.